# Content Rotator with JQuery Fix: how to scroll each thumbnail and not set?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, rotation, slider

http://tympanus.net/Development/ContentRotator/example2.html

Currently this Content Slider lets you scroll every 4 thumbnails (a set) when you click on the arrows. How can I make it so that clicking the arrows moves onto the next thumbnail instead?

Also, it is currently on AUTOPLAY, but once you click on a thumbnail, it stops. How do I make it continue to autoplay even after being interrupted by a click?

This is the tutorial page: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/07/29/content-rotator/

Answer (score 0):

The script for the slider can be found here:
http://tympanus.net/Development/ContentRotator/js/jquery.crotator.js

It's not a well written plugin and unfortunately the script itself doesn't allow for customizations (i.e. you cannot pass in a list of options). There isn't an option to prevent it stopping on interaction. To achieve what you want you'll need to edit the code.

I had a look at the code and the slider will continue to work so long as the variable config.slideshow = true. However, there are a number of event bindings that have code to unconditionally set the value to false. E.g.

```
$navNext.bind('click.crotator', function(e) {
    ...
    config.slideshow    = false;
    ...
}
```

You could remove the code where the value is set to false and that would solve your problem. However, since you're going to touch the code it's better to allow the plugin to accept options. You could make it allow an option like 'stopOnInteraction' where it basically does the following line in the event handlers:

```
if (config.stopOnInteraction) {
    config.slideshow = false;
}
```